# Set Previous View Controller As A Property Of The Current View Controller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

So, I am trying to implement a swipe right to go back to the previous view controller feature.

But when I have the following code in my current view controller, I get a black screen

```
- (void)initPreviousViewController:(GGMainViewController *)previous
{
    self.previousViewController = previous;
    self.previousViewController.view.frame = self.currentView.bounds;  //self.currentView is declared elsewhere (in the init of the current view controller)
    [self addChildViewController:self.previousViewController];
    [self.currentView addSubview:self.previousViewController.view];
    [self.previousViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
{
```

^I call this method within the previous view controller after initializing the current view controller, and before pushing the current view controller

If I change **`self.previousViewController = previous;`** to **`self.previousViewController = [GGMainViewController alloc] init];`** it works. However, I don't want to reinitialize the previous controller.

So how do I set the previous view controller as a property of the current view controller.

Oh, I am also an iOS first timer, so if this is not something that is recommended, please let me know.

Rationale behind my thinking:

Normally the user would just click a button, and the UINavigationController would do the trick, but since I am using a swipe functionality, I think the user needs to see the previous view controller behind the current view controller as they swipe the screen.

---

As requested
How I call the currentViewController from the previousViewController

```
- (void)displayCurrentViewController:(id)sender
{
    GGNextViewController *next = [[GGNextViewController alloc] init];
    [next initializeExploreViewController:self]; // If I comment this out, everything is ok (screen is not black,etc. apart from being able to swipe backwards
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:next animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: place the code relating to how your presenting the current view controller from previous view controller also...

Comment: Ok give me a min to get it on here :) @BhanuPrakash

Comment: @BhanuPrakash It's up!

Comment: How is this at all different than a typical navigationController stack other than the fact that you are using gesture to push/pop stack items?

Answer (score 1):

Your using the `self.navigationController` for pushing the current view controller, So you can call a method when ever the right swipe gesture fired.

Try this code in your Current view controller(**GGNextViewController.m**)...

**1.  Add the rightSwipeGestureAction() selector to the gesture recognizer which you have.**

**2.**

```
-(void)rightSwipeGestureAction
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the following lines were causing the problem. I just decided to comment them out and then it worked, without a black screen.

```
[self addChildViewController:self.previousViewController];
[self.previousViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

I can't just pop it with the navigation controller, because I want to create somewhat of a dragging effect, the user swipes (as they see the previous view controller below) until halfway through the screen, from where it goes to the previous view controller.